# Copy jar from maven repo using Antrun

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm copying a jar file from a specific project and I want to copy that using Maven's ant-run plugin.

Right now I'm using the following in the pom file: (and this works)

```
<copy file="${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/.../-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

      tofile="${project.build.directory}/lib/jarfile.jar" />
```

Only it's not very portable since not everyone has the m2 repo in the same place.

I've been looking for something more general like ${everyonesrepo}/org... but I can't seem to find it.

Is there such a thing or should I work with some kind of environment variable?

Comment: If you are part a a team you should create a default enviroment to everybody that way you wouldn't have such a problem. Unify all devs enviroment. It will be easier even to deploy other stuff

Comment: I know that's the better solution, but for various reasons this is how it has to be done (for now).